# React - functions as props causing extra renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some heavy forms that I'm dealing with. Thus, I'm trying to squeeze performance wherever I can find it. Recently I added the Why-did-you-render addon to get more insight on what might be slowing down my pages. I noticed that, for example, when I click on a checkbox component about all of my other components re-render. The justification is always the same. WDYR says

> Re-rendered because of props changes: different functions with the
>   same name {prev onChangeHandler: ƒ} "!==" {next onChangeHandler: ƒ}

As much as possible, I try to respect best the best practices indications that I find. The callback functions that my component passes follow this pattern

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
export function TopLevelComponent({props}){

    const defaultData = {name: '', useMale: false, useFemale: false}

    const [data, setData] = useState(defData);
    const { t } = useTranslation();
    const updateState = (_attr, _val) => {
        const update = {};
        update[_attr] = _val;
        setData({ ...data, ...update });
    }

    const updateName = (_v) => updateState('name', _v);//Text input
    const updateUseMale = (_v) => updateState('useMale', _v);//checkbox
    const updateUseFemale = (_v) => updateState('useFemale', _v);//checkbox
    ...

    return <div>
        ...
        <SomeInputComponent value={data.name} text={t('fullName')} onChangeHandler={updateName} />
        <SomeCheckboxComponent value={data.useMale} onChangeHandler={updateUseMale} text={t('useMale')}/>
        <SomeCheckboxComponent value={data.useFemale} onChangeHandler={updateUseFemale} text={t('useFemale')}/>
        ...
    </div>
}
```

In an example like this one, altering any of the inputs (eg: Writing text in the text input or clicking one of the checkboxes) would cause the other 2 components to re-render with the justification presented above.

I guess that I could stop using functional components and utilize the `shouldComponentUpdate()` function, but functional components do present some advantages that I'd rather keep. How should I write my functions in such a way that interacting with one input does not force an update on another input?

Comment: Can you add a little bit more code so we can understand. We have tools like `memo` and `useMemo` to reduce the unnecessary renders

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz Would you want the component specific function?

Comment: Actually, I could not understand which component is causing the change and which components are getting rendered which don't need to.

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz added some more code. I tried using `memo` but I was getting some funky results with the components that required more complex data. If that's the solution I'll try debugging my code with memo

Comment: are you using context as state? where is your state residing?

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz to change the state I'm using the `useState` hook. I added it to the op

Comment: I am close, how are you passing values to child components e.g `SomeCheckboxComponent ` if you are passing whole `data` then that is the reason

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz sorry, next time I'll add the whole thing from the start. You say that I need different state objects for every input in my form to stop one component state change to force another to self-render?

Comment: Did memo worked for you?

Comment: Take a look at [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback)

Comment: `useCallback` is the hook you want to use to create your event handler functions. they memoize the function so it won't cause re-renders.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem stems from the way you define your change handlers:

```
const updateName = (_v) => updateState('name', _v)
```

This line is called on each render and thus, every time your component is rendered, the prop has a new (albeit functionality-wise identical) value. The same holds for every other handler as well.

As an easy solution you can either upgrade your functional component to a fully fledged component and cache the handlers outside of the render function, or you can implement [`shouldComponentUpdate()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) in your child components.

Answer (score 4):

You have to memoize parent function before pass to children, using useCallback for functional component or converting to class property if you use class.

```
export default class Parent extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
    }

    onClick() {
       console.log("click");
    }

    render() {
        return (
           <ChildComponent
               onClick={ this.onClick }
           />
        );
    }
}
```

with useCallback:

```
Parent = () => {
   const onClick = useCallback(
      () => console.log('click'),
      [] 
   );

   return (
        <ChildComponent
            onClick={onClick}
        />
   );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `memo` for your child components to reduce renders

```js
const SomeInputComponent  = props => {

};

export default memo(SomeInputComponent);

// if it still causes rerender witout any prop change then you can use callback to allow or block render

e.f.

function arePropsEqual(prevProps, nextProps) {
  return prevProps.name === nextProps.name; // use your logic to determine if props are same or not
}

export default memo(SomeInputComponent, arePropsEqual);

/* One reason for re-render is that `onChange` callback passed to child components is new on each parent render which causes child components to re-render even if you use `momo` because function is updated on each render so in order to fix this, you can use React hook `useCallback` to get the same function reference on each render.


So in you parent component, you need to do something like 
*/

import { useCallback } from 'react';


const updateName = useCallback((_v) => updateState('name', _v), [])
```

Comment: How would you use memo when the value being passed to the child component is an object? I have some complex data object for some components and I've tried something like `memo(MyComponent, (_prev, _next) => JSON.stringify(_prev.values) === JSON.stringify(_next.values));` but this doesn't seem to work. Would I need to compare attribute by attribute?

Comment: @Axel Have a look at the updated answer about using `useCallback`. I hope it will fix your issue and you don't need to pass extra `arePropsSame` callback in `memo()`

Comment: I tried using `useCallback` to where all my callbacks look like `const updateFnc = useCallback((_v) => updateState('someAttr', _v), []);` but that only changed the error code of WDYR: Re-rendered because the props object itself changed but it's values are all equal. That error is appearing on a text input after clicking on a checkbox