# Why doesn't a function dependency in hooks cause infinite renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Following is the snippet [link to codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-sunset-csqnw):

```
// function getFetchUrl(query) {
//   return "https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=" + query;
// }
function App() {
  const [reactResult, setReactResult] = useState(null);
  const [reduxResult, setReduxResult] = useState(null);
  function SearchResults() {
    //  Re-triggers all effects on every render
    // const getFetchUrl = useCallback((query) =>  {
      // return "https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=" + query;
    // }, []);


     function getFetchUrl(query) {
       return "https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=" + query;
     }

    useEffect(() => {
      console.log("running effect: 15");
      setReactResult(getFetchUrl("react"));
      // ... Fetch data and do something ...
      // }, [getFetchUrl]); //  Deps are correct but they change too often
    }, [getFetchUrl]);

    useEffect(() => {
      console.log("running effect: 21");
      setReduxResult(getFetchUrl("redux"));
      // ... Fetch data and do something ...
      // }, [getFetchUrl]); //  Deps are correct but they change too often
    }, [getFetchUrl]);

    // ...
  }

  SearchResults();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>{reactResult}</h2>
      <h2>{reduxResult}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The output in the console is

```
running effect: 15
running effect: 21
running effect: 15
running effect: 21
```

I have checked out the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56178910/7879090) answer, and I get it that the functions get re-defined which causes the `useEffect` to run again(for the second time). But I want to clarify one doubt:

When the `useEffect` runs for the second time, it calls the `stateSetter` functions(which asks React to render the component again).

So shouldn't the above snippet run in an infinite loop?

Example and basic understanding picked up from [A Complete Guide to useEffect](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/)

Comment: Please remember to put code that you have questions about in your question. Feel free to link out to the "live" version, but questions about code without code are just going to end up closed. Take the code in that codepen, turn it into a [mcve] and then add it to your question please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `useState` react is smart enough to skip re-rendering if the state value 
hasn't actually changed despite a call to the `setState` function. (This is documented at https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update)

The example code you have included is slightly different from the linked code pen and will actually result in only a single "set" of console log message.

```
running effect: 15
running effect: 21
```

the sequence of events is:

1. Initial render, triggers both effects and updates both the `reactResult` and `reduxResult` state. This enqueues a re-render.
2. The component re-renders. In your included example you're using `useCallback` with no dependencies which will return the previous value, and therefore the the effects will not run.

On the other hand, in your code pen, instead of `useCallback` you redefine the callback on each execution, in that case you will get two "sets" of console message:

1. Initial render, triggers both effects and updates both the `reactResult` and `reduxResult` state. This enqueues a re-render.
2. The component re-renders. `getFetchUrl` is a local funtion and so is *not* equal to `getFetchUrl` from the previous run. As a result the effects will re-run. However `setReactResult` and `setReduxResult` are both called with the same value as before, so a re-render will *not* be triggered.

Comment: Yeah I forgot to update my code above to match the code in the link. Edited the question...thanks for pointing it out !! :D

Answer (score 0):

Your effects are only triggered when `getFetchUrl` changes ... and as it is a memoized callback (that does not get changed) the effects only run once.

Comment: I changed the code to match the one in the link....the question was for the one in the link. Thanks anyway :)